# Android traffic game developing

Tags: java, android, game-engine, andengine

I'm developing simple traffic educational game like https://market.android.com/details?id=cz.allianz.krizovatky.android . When the player taps on car sprite, it started to move with other cars. If player made a mistake in choosing car, collision happens.

My question is: what is the best way for implementing such game (game engine or direct Canvas drawing)? I'm not game developer, it is my first game. Now, I'm trying to use Andengine, it looks great, but I have not enough experience :( The main problems are:
1) How to make car automatically move along specified path with smooth turns?
2) How generate random map with crossroads?

Please, help me choose the right way of development this game. If I should use game engine, how I can solve my problems with car moving and maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your experience with Java, I would say that tweaking your own Canvas would give you more control for more work, but a Game Engine would let you get started faster with more design/implementation restrictions.

You might also find better answers if you asked the same question over at : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/